# Delphi iOS import/export data file using email

Tags: ios, delphi, mime-types, file-association

Assuming I have an app on iOS that generates a data file, and I would like the user the ability to import/export that file, how is that best done?

Import from email in xcode/objc:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

Is this possible in Delphi? (i.e. register an ios app as file handler for a specifc file type)

(I am planning on handling export through generating an email attaching a file? I suspect this is probably possible although if anyone knows for sure, feel free to share)

It has been asked why import/export across email is useful.

- Because legally EU/US law and cloud storage is difficult with personal data
- You don't need any desktop computers
- You can sync data between ios and android apps if user changes mobile
- You are not bound to any specific cloud provider or anything similar

Quote from above article where author explains where the file path is passed to the app:

> application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, passing the URL in the
>   UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey, or via application:handleOpenURL.

But since I have not used Delphi for ages (for mobile), I would just like to know for sure if Delphi supports this or not before buying a new version

Comment: Not sure why minus one. I have encountered multiple things possible in xcode being hard to do in Delphi for iOS. I have found how to do something in xcode (import) and want o know if possible in Delphi

Comment: I can't really understand what you are asking. How does sending an email constitute importing a file?

Comment: See the link? You register your app to handle the file type. Hence you can import/export data files over email without needing cloud or sync with computer or similar. Why is that useful you ask? 1) Because legally EU/US law and cloud storage is difficult. with personal data 2)  you don't need any computers 3) you can sync data between ios and android apps if user changes mobile

Comment: +1 but I recommend to rephrase your question and reduce to make the core question clear. From the linked article I can see that your app needs to register a file name extension / content-type with the iOS on the device. Then, the user is able to open attachments (or other downloaded documents) with your app.

Answer (score 4):

You can send files using email. I use the email component from [D.P.F Delphi iOS Native Components](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiios/) to send file attachments using email. I don't see any reason why you should not be able to send your data file as long as it is not too big. Use a file extension that is unique to your app.

You could also use iTunes filesharing in order to give your users direct access to your data file. Just set the [UIFileSharingEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW20) key in your info.plist and store you data file inside of the documents folder. This does require a desktop PC, but it is still a very nice addition to sending backups by email.

Comment: Thanks for the two suggestions! (I would need o at minimum support email since I would have to support switching from iOS to Delphi)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs,

I would suggest looking at perhaps saving the file to a server using FTP and Indy and then on the other device you can retrieve it?

http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=208397

- Set the TidFTP connection parameters
- Do a FTP put : // ftp.Put('testfile.txt');
- Perhaps have a Database with a column that you specify a file version etc
- Do a simple Get request if you want to retrive the file with the filename

or Alternatively you can save it to a blob field in a DB and have the other device read the blobfield if you don't want to do it via FTP

Comment: I would prefer avoid a cenreal server due to legal issues concerning personal data. Using email is a little of a hack, but will suffice :)

Comment: Also - this is user files with personal data - not global datafiles. The eason I want to use email is that the user is in control and I avoid he hassle os legislation with central database. (This is students at a school) The user controls his/her personal data soly and can export to email from e.g. ios ... and import again on android by opening the file attached (and vice versa)